# How can I create an array from a method with ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I make an array of 30 min intervals to 8 hours. so this ish:

```
[30, 60, 90, all-the-way-to,  480]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Range and the step method, then convert it to an Array:

```
(30..480).step(30).to_a
```

The result is:

```
[30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360, 390, 420, 450, 480)
```

Comment: I like this. Another way would be to use an open range and `take` so you can use it based on how many elements you want. `(30..).step(30).take(16).to_a`

Comment: @vcsjones More flexible but should note that open ranges only work in ruby-2.6.0 and above.

Comment: You can use Integer#step, but the calling syntax is a bit different: `30.step(nil, 30).take(16)` or `30.step(480, 30).to_a` or `0.step(480, 30).drop(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your arguments are

```
increment =  30
duration  = 480 # 8*60
```

You could use

```
increment.step(by: increment, to: duration).to_a
  #=> [ 30,  60,  90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240,
  #    270, 300, 330, 360, 390, 420, 450, 480]
```

which reads well. [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-step), when used without a block, returns an enumerator, which is why `.to_a` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this, but @infused answer is way better.

```
a = (1..16).to_a.map{|i| i*30 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Option selecting ([`Enumerable#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)) from the range:

```
stop = 480
step = 30

(step..stop).select { |n| n % step == 0 }

#=> [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360, 390, 420, 450, 480]
```